# Bootstrap Popover and image maps

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

http://jsfiddle.net/YsEqb/25/

Hover over his eyes. His glorious eyes.

What I'm trying to do here is get the popover things to appear above his eyes instead of above the picture itself. Pretty simple problem, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to solve it. I know the plugin isn't NORMALLY supposed to be used in an image map but it's the only thing I have to work with right now. And it seems like something I should be able to fudge. So, Stackoverflow, will you help me with my fudge?

This is a placeholder image, the real code will be used in a page where the images could be at different locations depending on the users actions. And there will be more than one calling the same map. So it has to appear on the specific image that called the map.

Thanks all.

{I can't submit this without any code. Here's the javascript I'm using.}

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#eye').popover({
        placement : 'top'
    });
  $('#eye2').popover({
        placement : 'top'
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using absolutely positioned divs? Or are they out of question.

Comment: Unfortunately out of the question. I did get SOME progress on it though. I figured out using css I can position the div where I want it using !important to rule out the dynamically generated css that happens when you mouseover his eyeball. Unfortunately there's no way for me to specify which one goes where. I can set one to pop up over his left eye, but his right eye is going to pop up there too. So.. That's where I'm at. Here's the Jquery for that: http://jsfiddle.net/YsEqb/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, here's how I solved this.

I decided to toss out the area map in favor of a more convoluted solution. Created a link tag, with all the elements to bring up the popover, and displayed it as an inline-block. Positioned it absolutely in relation to the container it is in. Then positioned it over where the eye is. No circles, but invisible squares work just as well. Who's gonna notice, yeah? It's a lot more repetitive coding than I like, but it works and doesn't slow the page down too much.